# chrome.tabs.executeScript only fires when the Developer Console is open

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an auto-login button extension for chrome. My code is the following:

options.html:

```
function gotoAdmin(){
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': "http://www."+currentTabDomain+"/admin"}, function(tabId,changeInfo,tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "login.js"});
    });
}

...

<img src="admin.png" onClick="gotoAdmin()">
```

login.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=username]').val('foo');
    $('input[name=password]').val('bar');
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["jquery-1.7.2.min.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }
],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

My problem is that when I open the options tab via the developer console and start gotoAdmin(), the jQuery events go just fine and the auto-login works, but when I click the image without having the developer console open, it will not do anything at all (not even open an alert) from login.js.

Comment: I am facing a very similar problem. `executeScript()` seems to not get executed when the Web-Console isn't open. I know it's been more than a year, but have you by any chance found a solution ?

Comment: No, sorry, I never found a solution. I eventually used a workaround that worked for my specific case.

Comment: Hey, thx for responding anyway. I managed to solve the problem (but I can't remember how - which worries me a bit :D).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know, I am joining the party too late, but -just in case someone lands on this question while looking for an answer to a similar problem (like I did)- here is the solution I used:

### First, things first:

The problem is that as soon as the new tab is opened, the popup window closes, which causes any JS executing in it to stop as well. So, since the `chrome.tabs.create(<specs>, <callback>)` was in the popup window, the callback function is never executed.

### The solution:

The solution is to have a background page (or better yet an **[event page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html)**) handle the tab creation process for you. Then, you'll have to initiate the process, by notifying the background/event page.

Step 1:
In the popup, use

```
// Add whatever arguments you need to pass, in <msg>
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg);
```

Step 2:
Have the background/event page receive the message and act:

```
// a. Listen for a message, adding a listener.
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  // I got the message, let's parse it.
    ...

  // b. Act upon it, creating the tab etc.
  chrome.tabs.create(<specs>, <callback>);
  ...
});
```

Take, also, a look at the docs for more info regarding **[Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)**.

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful. This other solution won't work for every case but if you don't mind the new tabs not taking focus then use active: false in the chrome.tabs.create and the popup won't disappear so allowing the code to keep running.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `tab.id` instead of `null` to the executeScript function and `chrome.tabs.create` passes only `tab` argument to the callback function, no `tabId,changeInfo,tab` :

```
   chrome.tabs.create({'url': "http://www."+currentTabDomain+"/admin"}, function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "login.js"});
    });
```

Comment: Changing that value leads to an error:
"Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 1. Expected 'integer' but got 'object'."

Using tabId['id'] causes the same effect as the original post describes.

Comment: Yes, I was confused by your syntax - you have used wrong arguments list of `chrome.tabs.create` callback function - fixed

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but sadly I still get the same behavior. It only works when I have the Developer Console open :(

Comment: ok, we need to go deeper ;) you have console opened in the Options view? There is no relevant code in the `background.js` ?

Comment: Ich have uploaded a test extension here:
http://www.wasd.ch/chrome/executeScript.zip

It shows the same behavior. When I click "Go!" the alert isn't triggered. If I right click on the extension and use the debug console and then click on "Go!" it works just fine. Thanks in advance for your help.