# Javascript only works when javascript console is open on chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

I have a script (javascript) that works in firefox but not in chrome or IE. I opened chromes debug console to find the problem. No errors are reported and the code works perfectly. Running it again with the console closed does not work again.

I verified that the version of the script is correct (not old and cached). The console does not report any warnings or errors.

I tried putting in simple logging that writes to a div at the bottom of the page - no information.
(in the debug console it works - including logging info in the div).

The function is the callback after an XMLHttpRequest is made to the server.

I verified that the php script is called by including error_log calls. The error_log shows the return value correctly. A page refresh also show the row has been deleted.

It appears as if the function removeRow() is never called unless the console is open. (method or reserved words conflict??) Tried changing the function name to delRow (including callback) - still not working.

All other Ajax calls seem to work fine.

A Code snippet follows:

```
var pos = 0;
var xhr;

function eraseRow() {
   var myImage = this;
   var fullid = myImage.id;
   // split row no and record id eg 5_1223 => row=5 and recordid=1223
   var idComponents = fullid.split("_");
   if (idComponents.length > 1) {  // check if image has complete row info
      rowid = idComponents[1]; // extract row number from id
      pos = parseInt(idComponents[0]);
      xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // only support IE8 or +
      xhr.onreadystatechange = removeRow;
      xhr.open("GET","valid_del.php$delrow="+rowid;
      xhr.send(null);
   }
}

function removeRow() {
   if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
         var err = document.getElementById("errormsg");
         var str = xhr.responseText;
         err.innerHTML = "Server returned "+str;
         if (str === "go-ahead") {
            var table = document.getElementById("tableid");
            table.deleteRow(pos);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

PHP (valid_del.php):

```
<?php
include(funclib.php);
if (isset($_GET['delrow']) && strlen($_GET['delrow'] > 0) {
   $recid = $_GET['delrow'];
   $db = createDbConn(); // function that connects to mysql server db
   $result = $db->query("delete from doclibrary where doc_id='$recid'");
   if ($result===true) {
      echo 'go-ahead';
      error_log('Script successful - returns go-ahead',0);
   } else {
      echo 'stop';
      error_log('Script not successful - returns stop',0);
   }
   $db->close();
} else {
   echo 'stop';
   error_log('Script not given record id - returns stop',0);
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put a good ol' `alert` in `removeRow`?

Comment: There is a typo in line 
"xhr.open("GET","valid_del.php$delrow="+rowid;" -> xhr.open("GET","valid_del.php$delrow="+rowid);

And are you sure that you want to use $? I think ? should be used instead!

Comment: a parenthese looks to be missing in the `xhr.open` line

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have noticed I made typos in transferring the code to this post.

Comment: My xhr.open line should read\n      xhr.open("GET","valid_del.php?delrow="+rowid,true);

Comment: Found possible solution: according to some posts I have found that mention Chrome having problems with asynchronous ajax calls. So changing the xhr.open call to `xhr.open("GET","valid_del.php?delrow="+rowid,false);` seems to fix it. Now to test why IE does not work.

Comment: Why is there `null` passed to `xhr.send()`? No argument should work as well if not better. For the MSIE issue you seem to have according to your last comment, I suppose you should test if `window.XmlHttpRequest` exists (web-browsing software), otherwise try to instantiate a `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` (_not_ web-browsing software, just MSIE-based malware).

Comment: Take a look at [this][1] , it seems the same problem


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290160/chrome-tabs-executescript-only-fires-when-the-developer-console-is-open

Answer (score 0):

I think the DOM is not ready, try to add your code calls into window.onload, or in $(document).ready if you are using JQuery.